# How do I change the value in an array? Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

How do I change the level value to the number 2 in the users array for a user with uid: 543? (Mongoose)

**Sample code:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Check",
    "balance": 1,
    "tokens": 2,
    "energy": 2,
    "ownerid": 623465,
    "users": [
      {
        "cid": 1285931,
        "uid": 0,
        "level": 3
      },
      {
        "cid": 3272234,
        "uid": 631,
        "level": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Check2",
    "balance": 5,
    "tokens": 12,
    "energy": 51,
    "ownerid": 171412,
    "users": [
      {
        "cid": 1874345,
        "uid": 543,
        "level": 3
      },
      {
        "cid": 2434512,
        "uid": 212,
        "level": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`positional operator`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) in this way:

With this query you are telling mongo that found the element where `users.uid` is 543 and then set the value where the query match (i.e. where `users.uid` is 543) to 2.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "users.uid": 543
},
{
  "$set": {
    "users.$.level": 2
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sIM6UkLFnkt)